# Oracle to SQL Server stored procedure & function converter

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Do you know of a tool that converts `Oracle` user defined functions to `SQL Server`? I used `swiss sql` online converter but it converts some of my functions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-oracle.aspx) should be able to convert certain PL/SQL functions to SQL Server.

However, since PL/SQL is so much more powerful than T-SQL, every tool will fail at a certain point.

Comment: it converts but sometimes it fails.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The functions can be converted, they compile in Oracle but sometimes they return the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

I can see trying to do this being problematic because you are changing from PL/SQL to T/SQL; they are different languages.

There are some some functions and operators that exist in one and not the other.  Depending on what you are using in the sprocs, you may have to do a workaround or a rewrite of significant parts.

Take a look at some of these

[Microsoft T-SQL to Oracle PL/SQL translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781/microsoft-t-sql-to-oracle-pl-sql-translation)

[oracle_sql_server_differences_equivalents](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/oracle_sql_server_differences_equivalents.htm)

[Reference sqlserver](http://psoug.org/reference/sqlserver.html)