# Dynamic TSQL to PSQL Conversion SDK?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, postgresql

I have a suite of applications that was designed against MSSQL.  We have a new vendor which will involve installing our applications there, but we absolutely must use Oracle in that installation. Other customers being unaffected, we want to keep MSSQL everywhere else.

Question 1: What are the best practices relevant to this situation?

Question 2: Is there a way (SDK, etc) to convert TSQL queries to PSQL dynamically (without manually entering them into a UI, etc)?

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781/microsoft-t-sql-to-oracle-pl-sql-translation

Comment: David: I saw that, but it seemed like OP was satisfied with a converter UI.  This wouldn't work in my case, as some of the queries themselves are built on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sense in converting just SQL queries since you will have to convert all database.
In this case there is very useful solution - Portable Data Objects. This technoligy allows to be abstract from specific database implementation level.
But unfortunately it is not your case since you've designed the app special for MSSQL.

Comment: I brought up the idea of bundling a database FILE with the application, but it was shot down. I'm really hoping not to have to write two of every query.

Comment: ...We have no problem in converting the database. The Oracle import/convert wizard accepted the SQL-generated scripts.

Comment: Basicaly Oracle supports ANSI SQL. If you don't use some things specific to TSQL may be it would work without some global changes

Comment: Some of them, like the selects and inner joins, but there are a lot of larger, complex queries and a lot of old cross-join style syntax.