# How to re-write this T-SQL statement to PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-migration

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @pimkeys varchar(max)
set @pimkeys = '69966,69965' -- input comma delimited values inside single quotation marks

SET @SQL = 
  'with basedata as( 
SELECT 
ec.Pim_key,pm.Parent_PIM_Key,pm.Item_Type,pm.Company_name,pm.Part_number,pm.Product_Desc,pm.Novation_Description
,ec.Name ,ec.Value 
    FROM edw..Products_PPS_Attributes AS ec
    join edw..DM_Product_Master as pm on ec.Pim_Key = pm.PIM_Key
    where ec.pim_key in ('+@pimkeys+'))

Select * from basedata
PIVOT (  MAX(Value) FOR Name IN( Sync_Code,Product_Line_Brand )  ) AS p'

execute (@SQL)
```

Comment: that's just a SQL statement from what I can tell, you don't need PL/SQL for that

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: but it uses dynamic SQL - you do need PL/SQL for that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it doesn't seem very dynamic though, it's just doing a string replacement

Comment: I know it is a SQL statement ...This statement does not work in PL/SQL Oracle though. So i was wondering is there a way where anyone can help me to translate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft T-SQL to Oracle PL/SQL translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781/microsoft-t-sql-to-oracle-pl-sql-translation)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Developer](http://www.oraclecom/sqldeveloper) is the platform Oracle provides for doing SQL Server migrations. [One of the features is our scratch editor](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/sql-developer-give-me-a-google-translator-for-sql/).

You can paste in T-SQL, and it will spit out PL/SQL.

Tools > Migration > Scratch Editor

[image]

It's not guaranteed to have a 100% successful translation, just like any other translator, but should give you a nice start.

Here's what we end up with, without any testing.

```
DECLARE
   v_pimkeys VARCHAR2(4000);
   v_SQL varchar2(4000); -- i had to manually add this after the translation

BEGIN
   v_pimkeys := '69966,69965' ;-- input comma delimited values inside single quotation marks
   v_SQL := 'with basedata as( 
   SELECT 
   ec.Pim_key,pm.Parent_PIM_Key,pm.Item_Type,pm.Company_name,pm.Part_number,pm.Product_Desc,pm.Novation_Description
   ,ec.Name ,ec.Value 
       FROM edw..Products_PPS_Attributes AS ec
       join edw..DM_Product_Master as pm on ec.Pim_Key = pm.PIM_Key
       where ec.pim_key in (' || v_pimkeys || '))

   Select * from basedata
   PIVOT (  MAX(Value) FOR Name IN( Sync_Code,Product_Line_Brand )  ) AS p' ;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Will try that!

Comment: @Ahmed i had to add declaration for v_SQL, but my simple test scenario based on your example seemed to work ok