# Convert SQL Server code to Oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-migration

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Alphaorder (@str VARCHAR(50))
returns VARCHAR(50)
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @len    INT,
              @cnt    INT =1,
              @str1   VARCHAR(50)='',
              @output VARCHAR(50)=''

      SELECT @len = Len(@str)
      WHILE @cnt <= @len
        BEGIN
            SELECT @str1 += Substring(@str, @cnt, 1) + ','

            SET @cnt+=1
        END

      SELECT @str1 = LEFT(@str1, Len(@str1) - 1)

      SELECT @output += Sp_data
      FROM  (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Sp_data
             FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@str1, ',', '</M><M>') + 
'</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) A
      ORDER  BY Sp_data

      RETURN @output
  END


SELECT dbo.Alphaorder ('juan') --> ajnu
```

Comment: Have you tried anything towards what you are doing. A quick google search got me to 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781/microsoft-t-sql-to-oracle-sql-translation

    http://www.sqlines.com/online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a badly written function to begin with.

If you need to do something like that function does in Oracle SQL, you can do it directly with Oracle SQL features, you don't need to write your own function.

Even if for some reason you **do** need to write a function, it is perhaps easiest to let SQL do the work for you (the same as you would do if your context was straight SQL).

Something like this:

```
create or replace function alphaorder(str varchar2) return varchar2
as
  output varchar2(4000);
begin
  select listagg(ch) within group (order by ch)
  into   output
  from   ( select  substr(str, level, 1) as ch
           from    dual
           connect by level <= length(str)
         )
  ;
  return output;
end;
/
```

Note that in Oracle you can't limit the length of the input or of the output string; you can only declare the data type. Then in the function itself you can check length and throw an error if the input is longer than 50 characters, but why bother? Let the function work in full generality.

Here's how you would call the function (and check that it works as required):

```
select alphaorder('juan') as alpha_ordered from dual;     

ALPHA_ORDERED
-------------
ajnu
```